# Let $G$ be a group and $H<G$ such that $|H|$ is $|G|$ divided by $2$. Calculate the right cosets.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Let $G$ be a group and $H$, a subgroup such that the number of elements of $H$ is the order of $G$ divided by $2$. How many right cosets of $H$ we can find?

**My attempt.**

By hypothesis we have that $H\leq G$ and $|H| = \frac{|G|}{2}$

Suppose, $|G| = n$ with $n\in \mathbb{N}$

Then,

$$G=\{g_1,g_2,...,g_n\}. $$

In this case, we have that

$$Hg_1, Hg_2, ..., Hg_n$$

are right cosets of $H$ in $G$.

Can I conclude that we can find  $n$ right cosets of $H$ in $G$?

Comment: Cosets of a subgroup are disjoint and the same size as the subgroup. If $H$ has half the elements of $G$ how many cosets can it have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that for any subgroup $H$ of $G$, the right cosets of $H$ partition $G$, and all have cardinality $|H|$. Now, writing as $e$ the identity element in $G$, the set $He=H$ is one coset of $H$. So any other right coset of $H$ must be a subset of $G \setminus H$, and have cardinality precisely $|H|$, and as the right cosets of $H$ partition $G$ there is indeed at least one more right coset of $H$. However, $G \setminus H$ has cardinality precisely $|H|$, so it follows that any other right coset must be precisely $G \setminus H$. Put another way, there is **exactly one right coset** of $H$, and this is $G \setminus H$. Furthermore, repeating the above argument replacing "right" with "left", $G \setminus H$ is **both the one right coset and the one left coset** of $H$.

Answer (score 1):

*Hint:* Show that, for any $g\in G$, we have

$$|H|=|Hg|.$$

Now recall that, for any two cosets,
either they are disjoint or they coincide entirely. They partition $G$.